# <%= link_to "My Blog", posts_path %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a continuation of this: [Ruby on rails link_to syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545951/ruby-on-rails-link-to-syntax)

I am getting the same error. I tried adding in map.resources :posts to config/routes.rb, but get this error instead

```
NameError

undefined local variable or method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x17dec58>
Rails.root: /Users/Morgan/blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
config/routes.rb:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   /Users/Morgan/blog/config/routes.rb
```

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? The syntax is different in rails 3.

Comment: from gem list - rails (3.1.1, 3.0.10)

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3 syntax differs from Rails 2 syntax, which used `map.resources :posts`.

```
resources :posts
```

Most things just exclude the `map.`, like `map.root :controller => 'home'` becomes:

```
root :to => 'home#index' # To Syntax: controller#action
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3+ you don't need to do `map.resources :posts`. Instead, just do `resources :posts`. What tutorial are you working from? It may be out of date which is causing your issues. Try using http://guides.rubyonrails.org